# regex lazy repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace 「.file extension,」 into 「,」

「1805171004310.jpg,1805171004311.png,1805171004312.jpg,」 into 「1805171004310,1805171004311,1805171004312,」

How can I make it lazy and repeat?
https://jsfiddle.net/jj9tvmku/

```
dataArr = new Array();
dataArr[1] = '1805171004310.jpg,1805171004311.png,1805171004312.jpg,';

fileNameWithoutExt = dataArr[1].replace('/(\.(.*?),)/', ',');

$('#msg').val(fileNameWithoutExt);
```

https://regex101.com/r/nftHNy/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the global flag `g`.

Your regex, isn't actually a regex, it's a string. Remove the single quotes surrounding it: `/(\.(.*?),)/g`, And you can remove all the capture groups, since are not needed here: `/\..*?,/g`

```js
const dataArr = new Array();
dataArr[1] = '1805171004310.jpg,1805171004311.png,1805171004312.jpg,';

const fileNameWithoutExt = dataArr[1].replace(/\..*?,/g, ',');
console.log(fileNameWithoutExt);
// or an array of filenames
console.log(fileNameWithoutExt.split(',').filter(Boolean));
```

If you want the file names individually, use `.split(',').filter(Boolean)`

Comment: What's the point of that regex group? `/\..*?,/g`

Comment: Thank you for saving my day.